# provide s3fs mount to docker as volume

Tags: linux, docker, volume, mount, s3fs

I´d Like to use a mounted S3 Bucket (using s3fs) as a volume within a docker container.

**I have:**
a mounted S3 Bucket (with s3fs) at /mnt/bucketname on my ec2 Machine
using:

```
sudo /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other,uid=500,umask=227,gid=500 bucketname /mnt/bucketname
```

and can read all files/folders in /mnt/bucketname.

This is the command i use to run my Docker Image (with interactive terminal):

```
sudo docker run -v /mnt/bucketname:/test -it Imagename /bin/bash
```

Within the Docker Container, the files (which should appear in /test/) are not present.

What might be the problem here?

Did someone use a s3fs mount and provide it to docker as a volume before or is this entirely the wrong way to do it?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for Self-Answering - but i solved the problem by restarting the docker service:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo service docker start
```

and voila: the s3fs volume is accessible.

best

Flo